# Delete a Google Storage folder including all versions of objects inside

Tags: directory, google-cloud-storage, version

Hi and thanks in advance. I want to delete a folder from Google Cloud Storage, **including all the versions of all the objects inside**. That's easy when you use gsutil from your laptop (you can just use the folder name as prefix and put the flag to delete all versions/generations of each object)

..but I want it in a *script* that is triggered **periodically** (for example when I'm on holidays). My current ideas are Apps Script and Google Cloud Functions (or firebase functions). The problem is that in these cases I don't have an interface as powerful as gsutil, I have to use REST API, so I cannot say something like "delete everything with this prefix" and neither "all the versions of this object". Thus the best I can do is
a) List all the object given a prefix. So for prefix "myFolder" I receive:
myFolder/obj1 - generation 10
myFolder/obj1 - generation 15
myFolder/obj2 - generation 12

... and so on for hundreds of files and at least 1 generation/version per file.

b) For each file-generation delete it giving the complete object name plus its generation.

As you can see that seems a lot of work. Do you know a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Listing the objects you want to delete and deleting them is the only way to achieve what you want.

The only alternative is to use [Lifecycle](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) which can delete objects for you automatically based on conditions, if the conditions satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Many thanks. Still Lifecycle doesn't let you configure by prefix. In other words I can't tell: Keep everything forever in this bucket, except objects prefixed MyFolder for which you delete all versions after 3 months. Right jterrace ?